# I or i, which one is correct?

Tags: word-usage

In the middle of sentence, which one do we have to use, I or i?

> "You heavens, give me that patience, patience I need!" *(King Lear, 2.4.291-305)*

or

> "You heavens, give me that patience, patience i need!" *(King Lear, 2.4.291-305)*

Can you explain the correct usage with reasons?

Comment: What does your copy of King Lear use?

Comment: It is used capital letter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The personal pronoun 'I' is always written with a capital letter in standard English. That's just the convention. Lower-case 'i' is very common in texts, informal emails and chatrooms, but is still considered incorrect elsewhere.

Comment: Is there any reason I is written with capital letter while the other pronouns are not?

Comment: nope, just convention

Comment: @ismailcem http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=I&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: That's a clear reason :)

Comment: I consider a lowercase i incorrect _everywhere_. At least when it's referring to the first person pronoun.

Comment: **the stand alone lower case i is never correct English, unless specifically using it to state the letter itself, like *"my favorite two letters are i and o"*. So always capitalize your I's! Especially on Stack Exchange!**

Comment: @cVplZ There's no need to shout.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I felt it was necessary since there are many users on SE who do not capitalize their I's.

Comment: @cVplZ This is not the place to address that issue.

Comment: Really?! English Language Learning isn't the place to address this? I get what you're saying but this is a universal problem.

Comment: I'm holding back on upvoting this answer because of the wording "is still considered incorrect elsewhere." That seems to imply that lowercase i is considered correct in texts, informal emails, and chat rooms. I don't agree with that. As far as I'm concerned, lowercase i (for the personal pronoun) is incorrect _everywhere_; it's just that in informal contexts, the writer may be too lazy to capitalize and the reader may not care.

Comment: The comments on this one have degraded to the point where it is i for I.

Comment: @Octopus Eye _see_ what you did there.

Comment: How about "Section I.B.3.iv states such and such, but one must take into account the criteria given in i" (yes, I know, just being a [pendant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedant)). I would urge the line to read: "In informal writing such as texts, emails, and chatrooms the [lowercase](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/59413/40348) 'i' may be used, though it is often still considered incorrect." This emphasizes the informal and incorrect nature of 'i' being used for the first person singular.

Comment: @Jasmine This comments section is for commenting on this specific answer and suggesting improvements to it. It is not the place to pontificate about English orthography. Indeed, ELL as a whole is a place to ask and answer questions, not to pontificate on English orthography.

Comment: @ David Z, @MichaelT: ower-case *i* is not acceptable in formal or semi-formal writing. As readers will consider it  substandard, and its use will lose the perpetrator examination marks, it is reasonable to say it is 'incorrect'. However, in personal correspondence and in chatrooms, who is to say it is incorrect? Indeed, users of chatrooms might well consider people using lower case *i* to be correct (right according to the established rules or ways of doing something, baving in a way that is considered socially right or polite. (http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/correct)

Answer (score 8):

> It turns out that this unusual convention was a bit of an accident. In
>   Old and Middle English, the word for “I” was closer to its German
>   cousin, “ich,” and it was often spelled “ic.” At this point, the word
>   was not capitalized. However, the pronunciation changed over time and
>   so did the spelling, losing the consonant c.
>
> At first, the new word, i, was left lowercase. However, it began to
>   grow taller than other words. It grew for a silly reason: a single
>   letter looks bad. Look at it: i. How sad. By the time Chaucer wrote
>   The Canterbury Tales in the late 1300s, I, the personal pronoun, was
>   slightly taller than its lowercase equivalent. From that point on, it
>   was typically capitalized.
>
> The only other accepted single-letter word in English, a, is a larger
>   presence on the page. Its appearance isn’t as offensive as the thin i.
>
> Today, though, some of us are regressing. In e-mails and instant
>   message conversations, capitalization conventions are backsliding.

http://blog.dictionary.com/whycapitali/